# Erlang gproc compilation failed

Tags: compilation, erlang, rebar

I seems to have some issues in order to compile gproc from uwiger.

I have fetched the ZIP [here](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc)

after unzipping, I have done

```
$./rebar get-deps
==> gproc (get-deps)
Pulling edown from {git,"git://github.com/esl/edown.git","HEAD"}
Cloning into 'edown'...
Pulling gen_leader from {git,"git://github.com/abecciu/gen_leader_revival.git",
                             "HEAD"}
Cloning into 'gen_leader'...
==> edown (get-deps)
==> gen_leader (get-ups)

$make
rebar compile
==> edown (compile)
Compiled src/edown_make.erl
Compiled src/edown_xmerl.erl
Compiled src/edown_lib.erl
Compiled src/edown_doclet.erl
Compiled src/edown_layout.erl
==> gen_leader (compile)
Compiled src/gen_leader.erl
==> gproc (compile)
ERROR: git describe --always --tags `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h .` failed with error: 128 and output:
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

I cannot seems to shake out this error, it won't compile correctly I have no gproc.app in the ebin directory.

I am using Mac OS X Lion.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same OS (mac os lion) as you and test the gproc in these days.

The author hasn't changed the source code until may 2, 2012. When did you got the source code?

But I got the sourcode from the git using "sourcetree" and fetch all patches, not got files from zip.
It compiles ok, although having little problem.

In addition, The "gproc_dist_tests.erl"'s eunit test has problem in mac os, you will find it later.

Comment: Hi Chen, Just fetched it yesterday... But it really seems to be a git error... I have version 1.7.9.5 which seems to be up to date (the last version is 1.7.9.6 and has been released five days ago)

Comment: What exactly have you done to compile gproc ? maybe I'm doing something wrong here...

Comment: Ok I have got it, instead of download the zip from the github website, I have cloned the got repository directly and now it works fine ! thanks for getting me on the way.